# How do I rename a Junos BGP group?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Is it possible to change a special place in Junos rather than delete?

In my case I want to change the ebgp-AS1009 to ebgp-AS23100, as far as I know only can delete the group ebgp-AS1009 then re-set. because there maybe too many params under the group, if there is a replace group name way, it will be much convenient.

```
root@AS1009-01-vMX# show protocols bgp          
group ebgp-AS1009 {
    type external;
    peer-as 23100;
    neighbor 41.241.157.2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a generic `rename` command in JunOS. So something like this should work:

```
edit protocols bgp
rename group ebgp-AS1009 to group ebgp-AS23100
```